# R executing T-SQL stored procedure with JSON as input

Tags: sql, r, json, shiny

I'm generating a JSON in R Shiny and the next step would be to send that JSON to SQL Server for further processing and fetching a results

When I use glue_sql to interpolate the json the resulting query executes successfully in SQL Management Studio but returns a data.frame with 0 obs. and 0 variables in R.

```
jsoninput <-'[
                {"start_date":20131231,"end_date":20151231,"fetch_date":20151231,"id":1},
                {"start_date":20121231,"end_date":20141231,"fetch_date":20151231,"id":2},
                {"start_date":20121231,"end_date":20141231,"fetch_date":20141231,"id":3}
                ]'

query <- glue::glue_sql("USE DWH EXEC usp_fetchFromJSON @p_json = {jsoninput}", .con = dbConnectionObject_DWH)

res <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = dbConnectionObject_DWH, query)
```

> USE DWH EXEC usp_fetchFromJSON @p_json = '[
> {"start_date":20131231,"end_date":20151231,"fetch_date":20151231,"id":1},
> {"start_date":20121231,"end_date":20141231,"fetch_date":20151231,"id":2},
> {"start_date":20121231,"end_date":20141231,"fetch_date":20141231,"id":3}
> ]'

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try by escaping the quotes in the JSON string :
Like this :
`jsoninput <- '[{\"start_date\":20131231,\"end_date\":20151231,\"fetch_date\":20151231,\"id\":1},{\"start_date\":20121231,\"end_date\":20141231,\"fetch_date\":20151231,\"id\":2},{\"start_date\":20121231,\"end_date\":20141231,\"fetch_date\":20141231,\"id\":3}]'`

Comment: Nope, tried escaping all " , {  }, and [ ] with no effect

Comment: Can you try escaping only quotes ? Do not escape opening and closing brackets / braces

Comment: same results :(

Comment: @feule83: Have you verify the content of the variable `query`? It seems yo me that binding is not working. Try also to print the value in SQL `select {jsoninput}`. I never used `glue_sql()` with implicit binding from the variables of the environment. I prefer : `glue_sql('select {a} as A,{b} as B',a=1,b='two',
 .con=DBI::ANSI() )`

Comment: In fact I use `glue_sql.multi.fct <- function(sql_multi_vars, args, connexion_bdd = DBI::ANSI()) { args <- unlist(list(sql_multi_vars, args, .con = connexion_bdd), recursive = FALSE);unname(names(args)[1]);do.call(glue_sql, args)}; `

Comment: Called by `glue_sql.multi.fct('select {a} as A,{b} as B',list(a=1,b='two'),  DBI::ANSI() )`